# Resolving glassfish 3 too many files exception (Richfaces 4.3)

Tags: java, glassfish, richfaces, glassfish-3, ulimit

we did a migration of our j2ee application on a Weblogic application server to Glassfish 3. Doing this we had to switch from Richfaces 3.X to Richfaces 4.3

A new resource handling came along with RF4 and static resources for RF-Components have to be handled by the application server now. Previously the static resources (like CSS or JS) have been stored on the webserver.

During our load test with 50 virtual users a "Too many files"-Exception was thrown (because of all the additional resources).

`ulimit -n` shows that our limit for open files is 4096.

Does anyone have an idea how to overcome this problem without increasing the ulimit?

We have tried to use the resource optimization feature from Richfaces, but the problem here is that the order of the resource loading can not be defined. So resources are loaded first which need other resources which had not been loaded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that your input streams dont close properly?

I once had the same problem and noticed that they were still opened. When I closed them, the "Too many files" Exception was gone.